# Javassist and named inner classes

Tags: java, proxy, javassist

i've a little problem with javassist, decorating a class with a methodhandler. The problem is that the method handler is working correctly with method1 in Abc class, but does not intercept calls to method2 in the Def inner class.

```
public class Abc {

  Def def;

  public Abc() {
    this.def = new Def();
  }

  public void method1() {}

  public static class Def {

    public void method2() {}
  }
}
```

simple javassist handling

```
ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory();
factory.setSuperclass(Abc);
Class<?> clazz = factory.createClass();
MethodHandler handler = new MethodHandler() {

  @Override
  public Object invoke(final Object self, final Method overridden, final Method forwarder, final Object[] args)
      throws Throwable {
    ...
  }
};
ProxyObject instance = (ProxyObject) clazz.newInstance();
instance.setHandler(handler);
return (Abc) instance;
```

How can i make that my handler method catch also method2 invocations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An inner class is nothing but syntactic sugar for defining two classes where, in your case, one is named `Abc` and one is named `Abc$Def`. In order to proxy the `Def` class's `method2`, you need to proxy it just as like the `Abc` class.

I assume you are creating a `Def` instance somewhere in the `Abc` class and want to proxy the creared instance's methods. In this case, create a factroy method inside of `Abc` and instrument the factory method to return proxies of `Def`.